# How can i make the user download the file when page is viewed in django

Tags: python, django, file

I am making the view to list the data in my view like this

```
class DownloadView(ListView):
    template_name = 'mytemplate.html'
```

Now in my that view , i want that when the page loads then i generate a pdf file in that view (which i can do) and then it should prompt the user with save file option. how can i do that

Comment: Can you clarify... DownloadView will contain your code for generating a PDF and then instead of displaying a webpage, you'd like the view to pop-up a save/download dialog for the PDF you just generated?

Comment: yes you r right. because later on i will make that view as download link. well if u think there are other ways to do that then i will do that. i don't know what is right way. i am new to django

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out the [django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/outputting-pdf/#write-your-view), it shows populating the `response['Content-Disposition']` with `'attachment; filename="somefilename.pdf"'`, but I think the following may work, if you've read the pdf file data into `pdf_data`.

```
from django.http import HttpResponse

def serve_pdf_view(request):
    pdf_data = magically_create_pdf()
    return HttpResponse(pdf_data, content_type='application/pdf')
```

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't recommend generating a PDF during the request or using Django to serve static files.

Your best bet would be to save all your PDFs to a folder and use Apache or Nginx to serve them and set the content-type header to application/octet-stream to indicate the response is meant to be saved.

--Edit--

I believe the right solution would be to generate PDFs dynamically, but use a task queue instead of doing during the request. If you need to authenticate and authorize the user requesting a PDF, do it in Django, but use X-Accel (nginx), X-Sendfile (apache) - or an equivalent - to tell your webserver to serve the actual file.

Django is not meant to serve static files. To quote the django documentation, "just because it can, doesn't mean it should".

Generating the PDF during the request is not a good idea because it makes users wait, requests can and will timeout, long running requests tie up your server, impatient users will hit refresh (repeatedly) and finally, it's a DOS attack surface.

Comment: Why not? Why not dynamically generate PDF and use caching mechanisms to store & serve the result? Automatically generating PDFs in Django has several advantages, authentication & authorization being one of them, dynamic nature of such PDFs being the other.

Comment: I'm not saying don't dynamically generate PDFs, but doing it on the request is not a good practice. Doing so makes the user wait, the request might timeout and opens you to DOS attacks. Absolutely, authentication and authorization are important, but you can do all that and still let the server serve the actual file by setting X-Accel (nginx) or X-Sendfile (apache) headers.